# Unable to close a modal in vue via v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm getting the error below from the console when I pressed on the button while it's showing `Close`:

```
"Error: Cannot find module './undefined'"

found in

---> <WhatsNew> at src/components/WhatsNew.vue
```

Below is the `WhatsNew.vue`

```
<template>
  <u-modal v-model="modalActive">
      ......
      ......
      <div class="whats-new-options">
        <div id="whats-new-checkbox">
          <u-checkbox v-model="whatsNewStatusInactive" label="Don't show again"/>
        </div>
        <div id="whats-new-next-button">
          <u-button id="whats-new-close-btns" full color="secondary" @click="nextNew">{{notViewedAll ? 'Next' : 'Close' }}</u-button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </u-modal>
  
</template>
```

```
<script>
  import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from "vuex";
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        modalActive: false,
        notViewedAll: true,
        newFeaturesOnUsedCount: 3,
        current: 0,
      }
    },
    methods: {
      ...mapMutations("client", ["updateWhatsNewStatus"]),
      nextNew() {
        if (this.current <= this.newFeaturesOnUsedCount -1 ){
          this.current += 1
        }
        if (this.current >= this.newFeaturesOnUsedCount && !this.notViewedAll) {
          this.modalActive = false
        }
        
        if (this.current >= this.newFeaturesOnUsedCount - 1) {
          this.notViewedAll = false
        }
        
      }
    }
```

I'm not sure what's causing the error, I've fixed it with a band aid solution by changing:

```
<u-modal v-model="modalActive">
```

to

```
<u-modal v-model="modalActive" v-if="modalActive">
```

However this doesn't feel right, I shouldn't need to use `v-if` to control the modal, the `v-modal` itself should be sufficient? But why is it that I get the error mentioned above? Thank you

Comment: what is u-modal?

Comment: That is an in house modal, but it's just link the one from bootstrap

Comment: In general v-model isn't used for opening and closing modals, since it's just a shorthand wrapper around input :value and @input events. How is this modal currently opened? With a method? Or is it open by default on the page?

Comment: This code (alone) works. Kindly post how you are calling/opening the modal. There might be something else not within the scope of the posted content

Answer (score 0):

Try using v-show instead and you need not to use v-model.

```html
<u-modal  v-show="modalActive">
```